# Zend - module structure does not work properly

Tags: zend-framework

Im trying to make my application module-structured but have a problem... My application has local address "myapp" and links to "C:/www/myapp/public" (Windows). When I try to access http://myapp (address based on virtual host) I get Default module executed (module:default, controller:index, action:index). But when I try to open http://myapp/default or http://myapp/faxes I get 404 browser page (not Zend exception). What am I doing wrong?
This is my project structure:
[image: structure]

And this is my shortened application.ini:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
phpSettings.upload_tmp_dir = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/tmp"

bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

appnamespace = "Application"

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"

resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.env = APPLICATION_ENV
resources.modules[] =
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts"
resources.layout.viewSuffix = "phtml"
resources.layout.layout = "index"
resources.view.titleSeparator = " - "
resources.view.doctype = "XHTML1_STRICT"
resources.view.contentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
resources.view.encoding = "utf-8"
resources.view.ViewSuffix = "phtml"
resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session"

pluginPaths.Duck_Application_Resource = LIBRARY_PATH "/Duck/Application/Resource"

autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Duck"
```

Comment: Looks like your `resources.frontController.controllerDirectory` setting is incorrect. It's usually easiest to run the default module outside the "modules" directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're using Apache as your web server.

The problem may be with your public/.htaccess file. The files contents should look similar to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

If these rules already exist in your htaccess, then you may need to check that your web server configuration file (e.g. httpd.conf) contains something like:

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
AllowOverride all
```

Documentation for the above can be found on the [Apache Core Features](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html) page. If you're still having trouble, make sure that you have the mod_rewrite Apache module installed and configured correctly.

Comment: Yes, Im using Apache. I have several virtual hosts and anything is ok - "AllowOverride all" is set for whole c:/www directory - but this one project doesnt works properly... ".htaccess" is correct too...

Comment: You were right, shame on me... I used to configure "Apache LDAP basic auth" for the directory and had set "AllowOverride none" there. Thank you.